# Get properties of class being extended returns empty string

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a User class which extends IdentityUser. I am trying to get the properties declared in IdentityUser (eg Email), yet when I call them the values don't appear to have been set. How do I correctly access the IdentityUser properties? They should be set on login. The other properties (named LGID) are being set correctly.

How I am calling the properties

```
var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
var user = new ApplicationUser(identity);
//do something with user.Email
```

ApplicationUser.cs

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string LGID { get; } = "";

        public ApplicationUser() { }

        public ApplicationUser(ClaimsIdentity identity)
        {
            IEnumerable<Claim> claims = identity.Claims;
            foreach (Claim c in claims)
            {
                if (c.Type == "LGID")
                    LGID = c.Value;
            }
        }
    }
```

IdentityUser.cs

```
namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     The default implementation of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser`1 which
    //     uses a string as a primary key.
    public class IdentityUser : IdentityUser<string>
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Initializes a new instance of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser.
        //
        // Remarks:
        //     The Id property is initialized to form a new GUID string value.
        public IdentityUser();
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Initializes a new instance of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   userName:
        //     The user name.
        //
        // Remarks:
        //     The Id property is initialized to form a new GUID string value.
        public IdentityUser(string userName);
    }
}
```

Login Method (Autogenerated)

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(LoginWith2fa), new { returnUrl, model.RememberMe });
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Lockout));
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I didnt understand your question. You are correctly acessing the IdentityUser properties, but you have never set them so the correct output is what you are getting " the values don't appear to have been set". Is there something missing from your question?

Comment: Can you share the base class with us?

Comment: If you set breakpoints in the constructor that takes a `ClaimsIdentity`, does the `if` condition in the loop ever return `true`?

Comment: is User.Identiy able to be cast as ClaimsIdenity?

Comment: An obvious first question is whether the identity has a claim with type "LGID". Have you confirmed this?

Comment: @LeonardoMenezes I was under the impression the IdentityUser properties were set when the User logs in

Comment: Use the debugger to look at the User.Identity properties.  The MSDN library for HttpContext.User has a specific warning: "However, if you want to use the members of IPrincipal from an ASP.NET code-behind module, you must include a reference to the System.Web namespace in the module and a fully qualified reference to both the currently active request/response context and the class in System.Web that you want to use. For example, in a code-behind page you must specify the fully qualified name HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name."

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for the tip, but that doesnt seem to work (Current doesnt exist in HttpContext anymore)

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling the base constructor also? I assume `public ApplicationUser(ClaimsIdentity identity)` should be `public ApplicationUser(ClaimsIdentity identity): base(identity.Name)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set them first xD
After login(!) call this in the action where you want the emailaddress.

```
    ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Something happend... Nothing here, user is empty!");
    }

    // Do something with the mail ;)
    string email = user.Email;
```